# How to make a Python "rust-Extension" module that behaves exactly like C-Extensions in terms of call overhead and processing speed?

Tags: rust, pyo3

The closer option I have found is [pyo3](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3), but it isn't clear to me if it adds any extra overhead when compared to the traditional C-extensions.
From [here](https://pyo3.rs/master/rust_cpython.html) it seems like such C-extension behavior is possible through *borrowed objects*  (I still have to understand this concept in detail).
Part of my question comes from the fact the build process (Section *Python with Rust* [here](https://medium.com/the-polyglot-programmer/rust-vs-python-on-data-science-but-why-not-both-d5f98080f632)) is entirely managed by *cargo* which references both *cpython* and *pyo3*.

For an example of approach that adds some overhead, but not rust-based, see [this comparison](https://gist.github.com/brentp/7e173302952b210aeaf3).

A related question is about portability, since it seems there is a kind of overhead-portability tradeoff.

For those who prefer to know the concrete case, it is about small hash-like operations that are used millions of times in unpredictable order. So neither a pure Python nor a batch native approach are going to help here. Additionally, there are already gains in a first attempt using a C-extension when compared to pure Python. Now, I'd like to implement it in Rust before writing the remaining functions.

Comment: Why don't you try both pyo3 and Cython on some sample code that mimics the code you'd like to wrap? I believe pyo3 should provide performance very close if not identical to that of a native extension, but that cannot be guaranteed, and the best way is to check.

Comment: I am sure you can use the native Python types exposed by [PyO3](https://pyo3.rs/master/conversions/tables.html) for a performant code. Also PyO3 creates native Python modules as C does. It is just an wrapper over the C API.

Comment: @EkremDinçel That's my feeling too. Do you know if my python package will be usable like any pypi one just by building it via setup.py or poetry? Or will it be bound to a specific python version or gcc/rust compiler used at build time in my computer?

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66467640/why-cython-embeded-plugins-has-higher-performance-in-cpython-interpreter-than-ru) which tends to show that PyO3 has twice the overhead of Cython.

Comment: @Jmb That question misses a lot of details, in particular how the benchmarks are run and timed. It looks like the Rust bindings include the overhead of calling a Python interpreter, while perhaps the Cython benchmark does not. We don't know (the question misses details), so we can't say it's slower (or faster).

Comment: @olyk As far as I know, a PyPi package might assume a C or Rust compiler, and if there are, it will build for any version that it is compatible with. In most cases, however, there will be a binary distribution (to avoid building locally), e.g., wheels: these are Python and platform version specific, and you'll have to build a wheel for each specific Python and platform.

Comment: @olyk I didn't even used PyO3 for creating PyPi packages but there is a [documentation for that](https://pyo3.rs/master/building_and_distribution.html#distribution).

Comment: @Jmb Thanks, in the github issue they kind of confirm the existence of an extra overhead. However, I implemented it and the timing was good enough for me. I didn't try to send it to pypi yet.